# Php write strange character on txt file

Tags: php

I to everyone, when i execute thi code for write on a file:

```
$fileTXT = 'prodotti.txt';
$newfileTXT = 'prodotti_2'.date("d-m-Y_h_m_s").'.txt';

if (!copy($fileTXT, $newfileTXT)) {
    echo "Impossibile continuare, impossibile creare file TXT.";
    exit;
}


$towriteinfile = "";
$fp = fopen($path . $filename, "r") or die("Couldn't open $filename");
$fpTXT = fopen($newfileTXT, 'w') or die("Couldn't open $newfileTXT");

while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line = fgets($fp, 1024);
    $arr = explode("\t", $line);
    $arr[7] = '<img src="http://link/imgHigh/' . $arr[7] . '.jpg" />;';
    echo "Prodotto: ".$arr[4]."<br>";
    foreach ($arr as $fields) {
        fwrite($fpTXT, $fields.";");
    }
    fwrite($fpTXT, "\n");
}

fclose($fpTXT);
fclose($fp);
```

I have thi result on txt file:

> 175;13563;desc;01;category;..............c etc etc.....
>   mercato.㰻浩⁧牳㵣栢瑴㩰⼯睷⹷獯畣慬楴挮浯椯⽴慣⽴浩䡧杩⽨　㄀⸀㄀　　⸀砀砀 漀欀ഀ਀樮杰•㸯㬻

the html code for image is written as chinese caharcter, why?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add content to the end of $newFileTXT from $filename ?

IF so, you should change:

```
$fpTXT = fopen($newfileTXT, 'w') or die("Couldn't open $newfileTXT");
```

to

```
$fpTXT = fopen($newfileTXT, 'a') or die("Couldn't open $newfileTXT");
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is probably interpreted as unicode (probably UTF-8). In unicode, characters can consist of multiple bytes. When you read the file, you just read 1024 bytes, which can result in half a unicode character at the end of the part that you read, and the other half at the start of the next part. When you start adding new characters inbetween, you get other unicode sequences instead, causing the text to be a complete mess.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem, i have passed any line to this function:

```
function cleanString($string){
    $string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);

    return $string;
}
```

My old string contained binary chars, i have cleaned the string and now all is ok